# planar max cut graph with constrains

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, max-cut

Given a planar graph $G=(V, E)$

I am looking for a max cut algorithm with the following conditions : some vertices are in one  of the partition sets?

Is the algo is still polynomial ?

I mean a selected subset of vertices should be in one set of the parttions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut#Computational_complexity